# ZAP detectportal.firefox.com

Tags: firefox, zap, captiveportal

I have set network.captive-portal-service.enabled to false.  When I try to run the default AJAX spider, with Firefox, on a URL I've manually browsed it starts  a new window with detectportal.firefox.com and hangs the spider because that is forbidden out of context.  I then check the about:config for the window ZAP opened and network.captive-portal-service.enabled is set to true.

How can I circumvent this?  The spider never makes it to the URL because of this issue.

Thank you.